# C Programming: How to make program end when user inputs a newline

Tags: c, string, input

I am building a basic C program that continuously asks users for a string input and prints out the entered input. The program is supposed to exit when a user enters a blank line. However, in my following program, even when I have a conditional that checks whether the user entered a blank line, the program still keeps on going until the user types an input. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char userString[100];
    while (1 == 1) {
        scanf("%s", userString);
        printf("USER ENTERED %s\n", userString);
        if (userString[0] == '\n') {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add `printf("first char is %d\n", (int)(userString[0]))`, and find the answer to your question without posting it here. it's a very basic debugging technique. You should practice some...

Comment: And you could also add `printf("newline char is %d\n", (int)'\n')` in order to find the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    scanf("%s", userString);        scanf("%s", userString);
```

`scanf` with `%s` will read the input stream until it meets any of the whitespace. Thus newline will not be included as part of `userString`.

Use `fgets` instead.

```
   fgets(userString, sizeof userString, stdin);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function usually read *space delimited* "token" (words, numbers, etc.).

Almost all format specifiers (including `%s`) skip leading *white-space* (all spaces, such as normal space, tab and newline). The only two formats that doesn't skip space is the `%[` format and the `%c` format, the first of which could be useful for you but I recommend against it.

To read *lines* I recommend the [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function instead. If the only character in the buffer is the newline then you have an empty line.